# Maximize window of another running program

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-4.0

How do I programmatically maximize a program that I have currently running on my pc. For example if I have `WINWORD.exe` running in task manager. How do I maximize it?

In my code I have tried:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximised;
}
```

Unfortunately that only displays my application. I would like it to maximise another exe, BUT if it cannot find it then i want to it to exit.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.setwindowvisualstate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Since I knew [`ShowWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx) method so I didn't look for a duplicate post. But, you will find the link posted by @PeterDuniho really useful. It also contains another way to find the window using [`FindWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx). Also it covers minimizing and closing the window. Also if you find it useful, you can vote for it to make it more useful for future readers.

Comment: I also added a simple example for [WindowPattern.SetWindowVisualState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.setwindowvisualstate(v=vs.110).aspx) Thanks @HansPassant.

Comment: @PeterDuhino I edited the post and added also an example of using [`WindowPattern.SetWindowVisualState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.setwindowvisualstate(v=vs.110).aspx) which is not an option in the linked post. Since usually users don't read the answers in a duplicate question, I believe we don't need to keep it as duplicate :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Using ShowWindow**

You can set windows state using [`ShowWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) method. To do so, you first need to find the window handle and then using the method. Then maximize the window this way:

```
private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD").FirstOrDefault();
    if(p!=null)
    {
        ShowWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
    }
}
```

**Using WindowPattern.SetWindowVisualState**

Also as another option (based on Hans's comment), you can use [`SetWindowVisualState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.setwindowvisualstate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method to set state of a window. To so so, first add a reference to `UIAutomationClient.dll` and `UIAutomationTypes.dll` then add `using System.Windows.Automation;` and maximize the window this way:

```
var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD").FirstOrDefault();
if (p != null)
{
    var element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);
    if (element != null)
    {
        var pattern = element.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern) as WindowPattern;
        if (pattern != null)
            pattern.SetWindowVisualState(WindowVisualState.Maximized);
    }
}
```